# Futures in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing, future, alice

Does Haskell have an equivalent of Alice's ability to bind a variable to a future?

```
val a = spawn foo;
```

where foo is some function.

I know Haskell supports channels and threads; I'm hoping for syntax as natural as Alice's to bind a value to a future and spawn a thread to calculate it without having to deal with the details.

Comment: Unrelated, but Clojure actually has those as well.

Comment: I've never looked into this myself, but I suspect that lazy IO can be made to do this in a really neat way, although it may have unsafeInterleaveIO under the hood.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `par` from `Control.Parallel` as in

```
a `par` f a b c
where
  a = foo
```

This is a hint to the runtime that `a` could be evaluated in another thread.

Answer (score 12):

Funny, I was just reading a new post by Simon Marlow: [Parallel programming in Haskell with explicit futures](http://ghcmutterings.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/parallel-programming-in-haskell-with-explicit-futures/). Apparently he and others have been working on some new parallel programming abstractions that are intended to be more natural and explicit than the `par` and `pseq` APIs.

Answer (score 7):

Not in the standard library, but

http://ghcmutterings.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/parallel-programming-in-haskell-with-explicit-futures/

```
data Future a = Future a

fork :: Eval a -> Eval (Future a)
fork a = do a' <- rpar (runEval a); return (Future a')

join :: Future a -> Eval a
join (Future a) = a `pseq` return a
```

Comment: "parallel" is part of the Haskell Platform, and regular lazy futures (`par` ) are already part of it.

Comment: Why isn't this `Future` api in the standard library? This is much easier for me to reason about than `par` and co.